# collection of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have the following result: Suppose $\mathcal{F}_{i,j}$, $1\leq i\leq n$, $1\leq j\leq m(i)$ are independent and let $\mathcal{G}_i=\sigma(\cup_j\mathcal{F}_{i,j})$. Then $\mathcal{G}_1,...,\mathcal{G}_n$ are independent.

Now I want to prove> If for $1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m(i)$, $X_{i,j}$ independent random variables and $f_i:\mathbb{R}^{m(i)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are measurables then $f_i(X_{i,1},...,X_{i,m(i)})$ are independent.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{F}_{i,j}=\sigma(X_{i,j})$ and $\mathcal{G}_i=\sigma(\cup_j\mathcal{F}_{i,j})$. Since $f_i(X_{i,1},...,X_{i,m(i)})\in\mathcal{G}_i$ (this part is the one I can't check), the result follows from the last result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be an element of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$.
$$\{\omega : f_i(X_{i,1},\ldots,X_{i,m(i)}) \in B\} = \{\omega : (X_{i,1},\ldots,X_{i,m(i)}) \in f_i^{-1}(B)\}$$
Since $f_i$ is measurable, $f_i^{-1}(B)$ has to be an element of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{m(i)}$.

At this point you have to ask yourself whether $(X_{i,1},\ldots,X_{i,m(i)})$ is measurable as a mapping from $(\Omega,\mathcal{G}_i)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^{m(i)},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{m(i)}))$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a separable metric space, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{m(i)})) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{m(i)}$. The latter is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $m(i)$-fold product of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. But this $\sigma$-algebra is also generated by $1$-dimensional rectangles. Consider the sets
$$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{m(i)}: x_k \in B\} $$
for some $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $k \in \{1,\ldots,m(i)\}$. Here $x_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of $x$. Then,
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{m(i)} = \sigma(S)$$
So for measurability of $(X_{i,1},\ldots,X_{i,m(i)})$ it is sufficient to consider these rectangles. Since each coordinate of this vector is measurable, we are done.